# Biblioteca Jfoenix não lista JfxButtons após adicionada

Tags: javafx

Estou com um problema e venho aqui para saber se alguém consegue me ajudar a resolve-lo. Instalei a library Jfoenix no meu SceneBuilder para funcionar juntamente com a IDE Netbeans porém, após a biblioteca ser importada no SceneBuilder como eles mostram que deve ser feito no site, apenas alguns JFX funcionam, outros como JFXbutton, JFXComboBox, JFXCheckBox, não são listados para utilização olhando o Log do SceneBuilder apresenta a seguinte informação:

> Exception for: com/jfoenix/controls/JFXButton.class
>   java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/javafx/css/StyleConverterImpl     at
>   com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:114)
>     at
>   com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:160)
>     at
>   com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:70)
>     at
>   com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:325)
>     at
>   com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:138)
>     at
>   com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:92)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/StyleConverterImpl
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007)    at
>   java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:545)
>     at
>   java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:83)
>     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:453)
>     at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:447)
>     at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:446)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     at
>   com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton$StyleableProperties.(JFXButton.java:175)
>     at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton.(JFXButton.java:155)    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:558)    at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
>     at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
>     at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2450)    at
>   com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:110)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.javafx.css.StyleConverterImpl     at
>   java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 30 more

Comment: Eu consegui resolver removendo o jar do Jfoenix 8 do Scene Builder e deixando apenas o jad do Jfoenix 9.

Answer (score 0):

**Passo 1:** Adicione o jfoenix.jar ao seu classpath, clicando em Library > Add Jar/Folder. (Como os componentes aparecem no seu SceneBuilder você pode ignorar o passo seguinte se quiser)

**Passo 2:** No seu SceneBuilder adicione-o também só que da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na janela que aparece a seguir clique em Add Library/FXML from file system e selecione o jar novamente.

Após fazer isso obtive o resultado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se de que está usando a versão correta do Jfoenix, pois o scene builder possui versão para jdk 8 e jdk 11, e neste caso se baixar uma versão do Jfoenix diferente da versão do seu scene builder, ocorrerá problemas de compatibilidade da biblioteca.

Verifique também se a versão do seu jdk corresponde a uma destas duas.
caso seu jdk esteja na versão 8 o scene builder também deve usar está versão, assim como a biblioteca Jfoenix.

Links para instalação correta da biblioteca com jdk8:

scene builder windowns 64bits: https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/thanks/?dl=/download/scene-builder-windows-x64/?

Jfoenix 8.x.x: https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/jfoenix/jfoenix/8.0.8/jfoenix-8.0.8.jar?